# Uglify.js messing things up within if statement

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I have this code

```
if (!win._hb_bids) {
    win._hb_bids = {};
}
win._hb_bids.hb_auction_id = helpers.generateCacheBuster();
if (config.isAmazon) {
```

translated with Uglify.js to this code

```
if ((p._hb_bids = p._hb_bids || {}) && (p._hb_bids.hb_auction_id = e.default.generateCacheBuster()), s.isAmazon)
```

I would assume that this code should be executed from left to right, setting `_hb_bids` property to an empty object. Instead, what I see in the Chrome debugger, generateCacheBuster() is executed first, and then it tries to make an assignment to `p._hb_bids.hb_auction_id`, and `p._hb_bids` is `undefined`  at this moment.

[image]

What is the reason for such a strange execution order? And how the code can be rewritten to work correcly after uglify?

**UPDATE:**
I found the cause of the issue. I had another part of the code doing iframe content refresh, and the `win` variable was pointing to an iframe window which was destroyed already. That probably caused this weird behaviour. So it wasn't uglify.js problem as I initially thought and stated in the title.

Comment: It's possible that there is no win object detected. What happens if you change your first conditional to if (!win && !win._hb_bids)?

Comment: I see win object in the debugger, but maybe somehow it cannot set a property on it. I've wrapped the second if inside the IIFE, and it still doesn't work.